# Why this code is showing "wrong answer" when i submit it to the online judge?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am quite new to python. I was solving a problem on an online judge. 
The problem was:

> Take the set of integers
>   `1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,14,15,16,17,18,19,...`
>
> First, delete every second number, we get following reduced set.
>   `1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15,17,19,...`
>
> Now, delete every third number, we get
>   `1, 3, 7, 9, 13, 15, 19,...`
>
> Continue this process indefinitely……
>   Any number that does NOT get deleted due to the above process is called “lucky”.

This is my code:

```
m=int(input())
n=2
while 1:
    if m%n==0:
        print(0)
        break
    if n>m:
        print(1)
        break
    m=m-(m//n)
    n=n+1
```

another approach:

```
n=int(input())
def Lucky(n):
 next_position = n

 if Lucky.counter > n:
    return 1

 if n % Lucky.counter == 0:
    return 0

 next_position = next_position - next_position // Lucky.counter

 Lucky.counter = Lucky.counter + 1

 return Lucky(next_position)

Lucky.counter = 2
if Lucky(n):
 print (1)
else:
 print (0)
```

when I compiled my program it was running successfully and gave correct answers to all the test cases. but when I submitted on the oj it showed "wrong answer" and was written "Possibly your code doesn't work correctly for multiple test-cases (TCs)". on the small test cases (like 2) it showed correct answer but when the number was bigger (like 30886) it was not showing any answer at all.

Comment: can we see the large test case?

Comment: 30886 and 89383

Comment: Your code, when run with 30886 enters the while loop, then `m%n==0` is `True`. So you basically just do `print(0)` and `break` the loop. I think, this is not the correct answer.

Comment: @SimonFink edited the question a bit. added another approach. but the end result was same. could you have a look on the second one

Comment: This is not valid python syntax. How can you even run `Lucky.counter = 2`. Gives me an error.

Comment: What are the full requirements of the answer? Might be not print 0 and 1 but return as boolean?

Comment: actually it was said to print 0 and 1